# Specific computer needs to flush DNS across multiple internet connections

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns

My laptop keeps getting disconnected from the internet, and the way I've been able to resolve it is through cmd command:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

This fix works for a few minutes and then I get disconnected again. This problem is happening to me across different internet connections and is not fixed when I reset the individual routers.

Some specifics:
The problem is not with chrome specifically - and I've tried using Edge with the same problem. The wifi has the "no internet" symbol.

It seems as though there is some issue specifically with my laptop. Any ideas what I can do to permanently fix this issue (instead of flushing the dns every few minutes)?

Comment: Run TCP/IP Reset first, then DNS Flush.  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer

Comment: What version/build of Windows is this?  Also, have you tried setting your DNS server to 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1 ?